# Delete object in JavaScript efficiently

Tags: javascript

On the server side, I have a mapping as following:

- **IDMap** hashes a *publicKey* to a metadata object containing {gameID, clientID}
- **gameSessionList** hashes a *gameID* to a gameSession object which contains all of the game's logic handlers

So my question is how would I go about efficiently deleting a gameSession safe and clean?

Right now, I'm doing

```
delete this.gameSessionList[this.IDMap[publicKey].gameID];
delete this.IDMap[publicKey];
```

But I'm not sure if it's a best way to do so. Like what exactly is happening here? My understanding is the key 'gameID' in **gameSessionList** is deleted and should be undefined if reference later, while the attached gameSession object is sitting there waiting to be collected by the garbage collector. Same scenario happens with the key 'publicKey' in **IDMap**.

Am I right? I guess I'm just trying to understand the whole process at a lower level and see if it's done right.

---

Or maybe I got it wrong, when doing delete as above I'm not sure which one gets deleted, the key or the value. And by 'delete' what is really happening?

Comment: Here's a good article about delete, for what it's worth. http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Comment: As far as I understand  standard  and  my  experience you're right.. I'd love to see a good answer on this

Comment: @RamblinRose: really helpful. Thanks alot

Comment: "*the key 'gameID' in gameSessionList is deleted, while the attached gameSession object is sitting there waiting to be collected by the garbage collector*" - yes, exactly that's what happens (unless, of course, the object is still referenced from somewhere else).

Answer (score 0):

http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

I use delete too.
But if you `delete` but the object is in use for others, nothing to do and `delete` `return false`.

`delete` was created for this and should be used for this. It is a native feature. No implementation will be better than that.

when `delete` print result to check `true`; In this case, success.
But if you use `var` to declare, nothing to do here. lol

For example, in console browser this:

```
v1 = 1;
var v2 = 2;
delete v1; //this print true.
delete v2; //this print false.
```